# Why Froala Editor Don't keep format when retrieve data from database

Tags: javascript, html, froala

I have used **Froala editor** to post some content for my website it is working good for insert data into database but the problem when I retrieved data back from database it don't keep the format as before and it shown all html tag and text too.

**Issue** text format don't keep after retrieved data from database and past into **Froala editor**.

Here is my Configure.

```
$('#eng_dd,#kh_dd,#ch_dd').editable({
            inlineMode: false,
            mediaManager: false,
            showInsertImage: true,
            imageUploadParam: 'up_img',
            setHTML: true,
            imageUpload: true,
            imageUploadURL: 'http://localhost/cootel/gotoadmin/image/edit_img',
            imageErrorCallback: function (data) {
                if (data.errorCode == 1) {
                    console.log('bad link')
                }

                else if (data.errorCode == 2) {
                    console.log('bad response')
                }

                else if (data.errorCode == 3) {
                    console.log('upload error')
                }
            }
        })
```

And here is my textarea

```
<?PHP echo form_textarea('eng_dd', set_value('eng_dd',$eng['dd']), 'class="form-control" id="eng_dd" placeholder="Your description of your slide"'); ?>
```

Here is the result

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you display the edited HTML from DB its entities are encoded most probably. You should make sure that what you output in the textarea is not encoded as HTML entity.